# What does the scaleToWidth 'ignore viewport' flag do?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I'm using [scaleToWidth](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#scaleToWidth) and it works but I'm not seeing any difference if I set the `ignore viewport` flag to true or false. I've tested this with content that is larger  and smaller than the `canvas`. Does this concern a zoomed or otherwise transformed `canvas` rather than the canvas boundaries?

Can someone explain, please?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Viewport refers to the canvas zoom.

The `scaleToWidth()` method scales the object with respect to the current zoom level so that running `obj.scaleToWidth(100)` while the canvas zoom is at 1.2 will actually make the object appear with a width of 120.

I believe the absolute flag is there primarily for internal use as part of the zooming logic since passing a value of `true` will actually multiply the object's size by the canvas's zoom value again which isn't particularly useful.